# Saving, storing, and retrieving user credentials securely

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, security, encryption, bcrypt

On my site, users can input credentials that let us access various web services of theirs.

One option was to store these credentials in a database, however storing any unencrypted credentials makes me nervous. I have experience storing passwords using BCrypt, which I believe is just one-way encryption to make sure passwords match.

In this case, I would need to be able to:

1. have a user enter credentials into a form (using SSL)
2. save the credentials to my DB (possibly encrypted using a Salt elsewhere?)
3. and still be able to read the unencrypted credentials at a later time (send using SSL).

How do I make sure this process is secure? Should I be encrypting in my DB, and storing a salt elsewhere?

Comment: You might want to move this question to security.stackexchange.com , as it is more about the procedure and policy on how to add an additional security layer for the sensitive data in case your server is partially compromised and less about the programming aspects of the implementation.

Comment: Ideally, wouldn't this be done with some sort of third-party authentication or authorization?